# Do long tasks decrease the timer more than short tasks during Hide and Seek?

Tags: among-us

When configuring a lobby you can set the number of long tasks and short tasks separately. Completing tasks in the Hide and Seek mode decreases a timer. Does completing a long task decrease the timer more than a short task in Hide and Seek mode?